# error checking date/time sync with ntpq

Tags: linux, date-time, ntp

When I check the sync status using the following command I get a "Connection refused" error

```
root@darkstar:~# ntpq -p
ntpq: read: Connection refused
root@darkstar:~#
```

What is the cause of this and how do I fix it

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my case the ntp daemon was no longer running or was no longer working.

A simple restart solved the problem

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp restart
```